# Click event not working for second time in SVG rect for safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, safari

```js
$("#rectang").on("click",function(event){
alert("click")
var cx,cy;cx=parseFloat($("#rectang").attr("x"));
cy=parseFloat($("#rectang").attr("y"));
cx+=10;
cy+=10;
$("#rectang").attr({x:cx,y:cy});
});
```

```css
#svgelem{
            position: relative;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-40%);
            -ms-transform: translateX(-40%);
            transform: translateX(-40%);
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <h2 align="center">HTML5 SVG Ellipse</h2>

<svg id="svgelem" height="1000" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect stroke="#ff004e" fill="none" stroke-width="4" id="rectang" class="zimageedit__rectangle" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="none" x="215.0975646972656" y="56.99761962890625" width="98.00119018554688" height="147.0017852783203" style="cursor: move;"></rect>
</svg>
```

Click event not firing for rectangle on second time in safari browser alone. The first click event works well but not for the second click. for all other browsers it is working fine. Is it a bug or am i missing something?

Comment: Click event not working for the second time Sorry. @Kaiido. I am using Macbook pro.

Comment: The click works every time for me.

Comment: Ok so that would be interesting as an [edit] (that it doesn't work the second time). Indeed there seems to be a bug with the `pointer-events: stroke` positioning on Safari. And yes, it's a bug. `pointer-events: fill` works fine though. Not so much we can tell you apart from filing a bug report to webkit.

Comment: @Kaiido Does the bug reproducible to you?

Comment: @JeremyThille Do you receive the alert every time you click on the rect?

Comment: Yes, well kind of : the cursor is misplaced at every update, but the click event works, once I find where it has been misplaced.

Comment: And the bug seems to come from `stroke-linecap` and `stroke-linejoin` attributes. After removing it, it all works well. https://jsfiddle.net/pc8orxeg/2/

Comment: Yes, I get an alert at every click